# Capybara 2.1 Error uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, rspec-rails

I just upgraded my Capybara Gem from version 1 to 2.1.0 (latest). Based on Capybara Readme, I added this following lines to my spec_helper.rb inside Spork.prefork block

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
```

But, I got an error

```
/home/user_1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rails.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
```

Did I miss something in order capybara to work properly ?

Comment: could it be that you have guard installed and try using > rspec in your console? This was my case.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you require 'rspec/rails' first:

```
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
```

If you require 'capybara/rails' first, you'll get that error.

Answer (score 12):

In your **spec_helper.rb** file, this error can be caused from adding the `require 'capybara/rails'` line in the top of the file's code.

Instead, if you look about half-way down that auto-generated spec_helper.rb file, you will see something like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

Add the `require 'capybara/rails'` line after those lines so that it looks like:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails' #######
```

*(you don't need the hashes, those were just to highlight the insertion location)*

Hopefully this helps you or someone else out there...

Comment: Adding `require 'capybara/rspec'` to your `spec_helper.rb` file was enough for me to make it work. I read about it [here](https://kolosek.com/rails-capybara-setup/).

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me for capybara -v 3.24**

Open the spec_helper.rb file. This file can be found inside the spec folder of your application.

Locate the line below in the spec_helper.rb file

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Add

```
require 'capybara/rails'
```

just directly under the

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

line

Save and close the file

That's all

**I hope this helps.**